# Как передать токен OAuth в другие Activity

Tags: java, android, oauth

Использую account manager, как получить токен в другом activity?

использовать SharedPreferences или наследовать все activity от базовой activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    this.authToken = null;
    this.mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
    this.mAccountManager.getAuthTokenByFeatures(AccountUtils.ACCOUNT_TYPE, AccountUtils.AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, null, this, null, null, new GetAuthTokenCallback(), null);

}

private class GetAuthTokenCallback implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
        Bundle bundle;
        try {
            bundle = result.getResult();
            final Intent intent = (Intent) bundle.get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
            if (intent != null) {
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            } else {
                authToken = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                final String accountName = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);

                AuthHelper.setLastUsedAccountName(AccountUtils.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountName);

                Account account = AccountUtils.getAccount(SplashScreen.this, accountName);
                if (account == null) {
                    account = new Account(accountName, AccountUtils.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
                    mAccountManager.setAuthToken(account, AccountUtils.AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, authToken);
                }

            }
        } catch(OperationCanceledException e) {
            finish();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Как правильно обрабатывать случаи истечения срока действия токена и смены пароля пользователем?

Answer (score 1):

Если токен надо хранить - то sharedPrefernces, если же просто передать в другой активити после `finish(),` то можно использовать [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: получается, в mainactivity вызываем getAuthTokenByFeatures, если токен  есть, то во всех остальных берем из sharedPrefernces, если нет -> loginactivity?

Comment: а если токен истек, получаем 401, вызываем invalidate, а если юзер изменил пароль, и находится не в main? как запусить login?  (добавить в каждую activity onActivityResult?)

Comment: Подробностей и алгоритмов в ваших кишках я не знаю, поэтому и дал только общую наводку.